# Getting several lines from a table in SQL Server and list them

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I have a list with vehicles likes this:

[image]

Let's say I would like to display only cars with the ECUs TMS1 and C200. How do I do that?

I have inserted this function:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
        (@pString NVARCHAR(4000), @pDelimiter NCHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
   WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1) <> ''
;
GO
```

and created this stored procedure:

```
Alter Procedure [db_ddladmin].[spGetVehicles]
(
    @ECU nvarchar(20),
    @Identifiers nvarchar(20)
)
AS
Begin 
    SELECT * 
    FROM db_ddladmin.View_VehicleReadouts 
    WHERE ECU IN (SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[SplitString](@ECU,',') )
      AND Identifier IN (SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[SplitString](@Identifiers, ',')) 
END
```

And I execute this stored procedure by this query:

```
EXEC [db_ddladmin].[spGetVehicles] @ECU = 'EBS7,ALM1', @Identifiers = '88'
```

I get a list with all the vehicles containing those ECUs and Identifiers. But the thing is that I would only like to display vehicles that has both of the ECUs I have written there and not vehicles that has only one of those desired ECUs. How do I do that?

Comment: You have no column called `Vehicle`.  What identifies a vehicle?

Comment: A Vehicle contains different ECUs and those different ECUs can be identified using different numbers such as 88, 89. As you can see in the picture above is that a Vehicle always has a name, in this case "aamir". Aamir contains as mentioned around 20 different ECUs where every ECU has around 5 different Identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with aggregation and `having`.  The idea is to count the number of matches:

```
with items(item) as (
      select Item 
      from dbo.SplitString(@ECU, ',')
     )
select ??
from db_ddladmin.View_VehicleReadouts
where ecu in (select items.item from items)
group by ??
having count(*) = (select count(*) from items);
```

The `??` represents the column that specifies the vehicle.

If there can be duplicates in the table, then use `count(distinct ecu)` rather than `count(*)` in the `having` clause.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little bit confused. You say that `??` specifies the vehicle. I don't quite understand that part.

Comment: I tried using Name where you inserted ?? but it gives me the same results. It shows vehicle that has one of the ECU but not the other and it shows duplicate values aswell @Gordon

Comment: If you use `count(distinct ecu)`, then the returned values would have to have all the items.

Comment: Thanks that solved one problem. I Tried sorting out vehicles with three different variables. This is my execution code `EXEC [db_ddladmin].[spGetVehicles] @ECU = 'EBS7, ALM1', @Identifiers = '88', @value ='2459579,2403967'` But it seems like it doesnt work. I defined @value the same way i defnied ECU and Identifier. What im i doing wrong?